# Strange result of highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use http://highcharts.com and there is really strange result. So, my data looks like:

```
Value | Date
1507   2013-02-03
734    2013-02-02
0      2013-02-01
225    2013-01-31 *Graphic miss*
672    2013-01-30 *Graphic miss*
692    2013-01-29 *Graphic miss* <--- This value gone to 1 february
910    2013-01-28
314    2013-01-27
```

[image]

[image]

I miss three days (29 January, 30, 31).

When I get data from the database, I convert it like so:

```
var lines = [];
try {
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, line) {
        var dateArr = line.date.split('-');
        lines.push([
            Date.UTC(dateArr[0],dateArr[1],dateArr[2]),
            parseInt(line.num_chips)
        ]);
    });
} catch(e) {}
```

What could have gone wrong?

**My mistake in Date.UTC converting!**

In the database I have January as month "01". But to pass January in UTC, I have to pass in "0".

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I've found my mistake- thats in Date.UTC. 0 - January, but in database my January - 01.

Comment: ya.For january its 0. [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

Comment: @user1612334 : If your answer is solved, you should answer your own question, so that it helps someone in the future facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my mistake- thats in Date.UTC. 0 - January, but in database my January - 01

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this I think you issue is that you time series data is not in ascending chronological order. Your first point needs to be the earliest date and your last point needs to be your latest date in the data.